# Enumitem inline span to \textwidth

Tags: enumitem

I am using `enumitem` for horizontal lists. However, I would like to spread the items over the entire row. I've tried with `wide` parameter, but it puts the space between the label and text. I can adjust the absolute value with `itemjoin`, but this should be redone for all lists considering the number of items and their text length. Is there a way to automate this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eget ligula eu lectus lobortis condimentum. Aliquam nonummy auctor massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla at risus. Quisque purus magna, auctor et, sagittis ac, posuere eu, lectus. Nam mattis, felis ut adipiscing.

List:

\begin{enumerate*}[before=\noindent, wide=\parindent]
    \item Item X
    \item Item Y
    \item Item Z
\end{enumerate*}

Desired list:

\begin{enumerate*}[before=\noindent, itemjoin = \hspace{0.32\linewidth}]
    \item Item X
    \item Item Y
    \item Item Z
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would `itemjoin=\hfill` work for you (or maybe better `itemjoin=\hspace{10pt plus 1fill}` to set a minimum space of 10pt between the items)?

Comment: @JasperHabicht no :/

Comment: it puts all items together without any spaces

Comment: See my answer below ...

Comment: it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `itemjoin=\hspace{10pt plus 1fill}` to get a minimum width of 10pt between the items (I added `~` to avoid a line break at this position):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent\hrule

\bigskip

\begin{enumerate*}[before=\noindent, itemjoin=\hspace{10pt plus 1fill}]
    \item Item~X
    \item Item~Y
    \item Item~Z
\end{enumerate*}

\bigskip

\begin{enumerate*}[before=\noindent, itemjoin=\hspace{10pt plus 1fill}]
    \item Item~S
    \item Item~T
    \item Item~U
    \item Item~V
    \item Item~W
    \item Item~X
    \item Item~Y 
    \item Item~Z
\end{enumerate*}

\bigskip

\begin{enumerate*}[before=\noindent, itemjoin=\hspace{10pt plus 1fill}]
    \item This is a long item
    \item This is an even longer item that requires a lot of space
    \item This is also a long item
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

[image]